# Magento 2 Bundle\Custom Option New Field Not Show Value

Tags: magento2

What we have:

di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel">
    <plugin name="bundle_option_sku" type="SY\Configurator\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel" sortOrder="1000"/>
</type>
```

UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace SY\Configurator\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface {
    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ){
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.3', '<')) {
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('catalog_product_bundle_option'),
                'option_sku',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' => 'Sku'
                ]
            );
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Plugin:

```
class BundlePanel {
    public function afterModifyMeta(
        \Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel $subject,
        $meta
    ){
        $meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['option_info']['children']['option_sku'] = $this->getSkuFieldConfig(
            11,
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Sku'),
                            'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/component/static-type-input',
                            'valueUpdate' => 'input',
                            'imports' => [
                                'optionId' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.option_id'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );
        return $meta;
    }
    protected function getSkuFieldConfig($sortOrder, array $options = []){
        return array_replace_recursive(
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Sku'),
                            'componentType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'option_sku',
                            // 'dataScope' => 'title',
                            'dataType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
                            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                            'validation' => [
                                'required-entry' => true,
                                // 'no-whitespace' => true,
                                'validate-alphanum-with-spaces' => true
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            $options
        );
    }
}
```

All is ok, showing and saving, but saved values not appends, what is need to do?

Comment: found solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/183583/48697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite  class:

```
\Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite
```

Look at method name `modifyData` and find below code:

```
$data[$modelId][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS][]
```

Please add your custom field  key '`option_sku`' to  above array

**Please follow below step**

1) crete `di.xml` file at `SY/Configurator/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite" type="SY\Configurator\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite" />
<type name="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel">
    <plugin name="bundle_option_sku" type="SY\Configurator\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel" sortOrder="1000"/>
</type>
</config>
```

2) create `Composite.php` file at

**SY/Configurator/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Composite.php**

```
<?php

namespace SY\Configurator\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel;

class Composite extends \Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite {

    public function modifyData(array $data) {

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product */
        $product = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $modelId = $product->getId();
        $isBundleProduct = $product->getTypeId() === Type::TYPE_CODE;
        if ($isBundleProduct && $modelId) {
            $data[$modelId][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS] = [];
            $extra_options = $this->getEtra_attributes($product);
            /** @var \Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\OptionInterface $option */
            foreach ($this->optionsRepository->getList($product->getSku()) as $option) {
                $selections = [];
                foreach ($option->getProductLinks() as $productLink) {
                    $linkedProduct = $this->productRepository->get($productLink->getSku());
                    $integerQty = 1;
                    if ($linkedProduct->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()) {
                        if ($linkedProduct->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getIsQtyDecimal()) {
                            $integerQty = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    $selections[] = [
                        'selection_id' => $productLink->getId(),
                        'option_id' => $productLink->getOptionId(),
                        'product_id' => $linkedProduct->getId(),
                        'name' => $linkedProduct->getName(),
                        'sku' => $linkedProduct->getSku(),
                        'is_default' => ($productLink->getIsDefault()) ? '1' : '0',
                        'selection_price_value' => $productLink->getPrice(),
                        'selection_price_type' => $productLink->getPriceType(),
                        'selection_qty' => (bool) $integerQty ? (int) $productLink->getQty() : $productLink->getQty(),
                        'selection_can_change_qty' => $productLink->getCanChangeQuantity(),
                        'selection_qty_is_integer' => (bool) $integerQty,
                        'position' => $productLink->getPosition(),
                        'delete' => '',
                    ];
                }

                $data[$modelId][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS][] = [
                    'position' => $option->getPosition(),
                    'option_id' => $option->getOptionId(),
                    'title' => $option->getTitle(),
                    'option_sku' => $extra_options[$option->getOptionId()]['option_sku'],
                    'default_title' => $option->getDefaultTitle(),
                    'type' => $option->getType(),
                    'required' => ($option->getRequired()) ? '1' : '0',
                    'bundle_selections' => $selections,
                ];
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function getEtra_attributes($product) {
        $optionArray = array();
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
        $optionsCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getOptionsCollection($product);
        foreach ($optionsCollection as $options) {
            $optionArray[$options->getOptionId()]['option_sku'] = $options->getMaximumQuantity();

        }

        return $optionArray;
    }

}
```

Comment: Code can be little bit improved. Please refer below answer.

Answer (score 7):

1) Create plugin, preferences in `app/code/ABC/Product/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel">
        <plugin name="bundle_addtional_options" type="ABC\Product\Plugin\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel" sortOrder="1000"/>
    </type>
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite" type="ABC\Product\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\OptionList" type="ABC\Product\Model\Bundle\Product\OptionList"/>
</config>
```

2) Plugin will be as follows `ABC/Product/Plugin/Bundle/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/BundlePanel.php`

```
<?php

namespace ABC\Product\Plugin\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Form;;

class BundlePanel
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel $subject
     * @param $meta
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterModifyMeta(\Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel $subject, $meta)
    {
        $fieldSet = [
            'min_qty' => [
                'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Number::NAME,
                'formElement'   => Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                'label' => 'Min Qty',
                'dataScope' => 'min_qty',
                'sortOrder' => 40
            ],
            'max_qty' => [
                'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Number::NAME,
                'formElement'   => Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                'label' => 'Max Qty',
                'dataScope' => 'max_qty',
                'sortOrder' => 45
            ],
            'is_lease_machine' => [
                'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Boolean::NAME,
                'formElement'   => Form\Element\Select::NAME,
                'label' => 'Is Lease Machine',
                'dataScope' => 'is_lease_machine',
                'sortOrder' => 50,
                'options' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __('No'),
                        'value' => 0
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __('Yes'),
                        'value' => 1
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        foreach ($fieldSet as $filed => $fieldOptions)
        {
            $meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']
            ['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['option_info']['children'][$filed] = $this->getSelectionCustomText($fieldOptions);
        }

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * @param $fieldOptions
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getSelectionCustomText($fieldOptions)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                        'dataType'      => $fieldOptions['dataType'],
                        'formElement'   => $fieldOptions['formElement'],
                        'label'         => __($fieldOptions['label']),
                        'dataScope'     => $fieldOptions['dataScope'],
                        'sortOrder'     => $fieldOptions['sortOrder'],
                        'options'       => array_key_exists('options', $fieldOptions) ? $fieldOptions['options']: "",
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

3) Preference 1 as follows (to save data):

```
<?php

namespace ABC\Product\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel;

class Composite extends \Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite
{
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product */
        $product = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $modelId = $product->getId();
        $isBundleProduct = $product->getTypeId() === Type::TYPE_CODE;
        if ($isBundleProduct && $modelId) {
            $data[$modelId][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS] = [];

            /** @var \Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\OptionInterface $option */
            foreach ($this->optionsRepository->getList($product->getSku()) as $option) {
                $selections = [];
                foreach ($option->getProductLinks() as $productLink) {
                    $linkedProduct = $this->productRepository->get($productLink->getSku());
                    $integerQty = 1;
                    if ($linkedProduct->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()) {
                        if ($linkedProduct->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getIsQtyDecimal()) {
                            $integerQty = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    $selections[] = [
                        'selection_id' => $productLink->getId(),
                        'option_id' => $productLink->getOptionId(),
                        'product_id' => $linkedProduct->getId(),
                        'name' => $linkedProduct->getName(),
                        'sku' => $linkedProduct->getSku(),
                        'is_default' => ($productLink->getIsDefault()) ? '1' : '0',
                        'selection_price_value' => $productLink->getPrice(),
                        'selection_price_type' => $productLink->getPriceType(),
                        'selection_qty' => (bool)$integerQty ? (int)$productLink->getQty() : $productLink->getQty(),
                        'selection_can_change_qty' => $productLink->getCanChangeQuantity(),
                        'selection_qty_is_integer' => (bool)$integerQty,
                        'position' => $productLink->getPosition(),
                        'delete' => '',
                    ];
                }

                $data[$modelId][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS][] = [
                    'position' => $option->getPosition(),
                    'option_id' => $option->getOptionId(),
                    'title' => $option->getTitle(),
                    'min_qty' => $option->getMinQty(), //new field
                    'max_qty' => $option->getMaxQty(), //new field
                    'is_lease_machine' => $option->getIsLeaseMachine(), //new field
                    'default_title' => $option->getDefaultTitle(),
                    'type' => $option->getType(),
                    'required' => ($option->getRequired()) ? '1' : '0',
                    'bundle_selections' => $selections,
                ];
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

4) Preference 2 as follows (to retrieve data):

```
<?php

namespace ABC\Product\Model\Bundle\Product;

class OptionList extends \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\OptionList
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product
     * @return \Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\OptionInterface[]
     */
    public function getItems(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product)
    {
        $optionCollection = $this->type->getOptionsCollection($product);
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($optionCollection);
        $optionList = [];
        /** @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\Option $option */
        foreach ($optionCollection as $option) {
            $productLinks = $this->linkList->getItems($product, $option->getOptionId());
            /** @var \Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\OptionInterface $optionDataObject */
            $optionDataObject = $this->optionFactory->create();
            $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
                $optionDataObject,
                $option->getData(),
                \Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\OptionInterface::class
            );
            $optionDataObject->setOptionId($option->getOptionId())
                ->setTitle($option->getTitle() === null ? $option->getDefaultTitle() : $option->getTitle())
                ->setDefaultTitle($option->getDefaultTitle())
                ->setSku($product->getSku())
                ->setMinQty($option->getMinQty()) // retrieve "min_qty" from db
                ->setMaxQty($option->getMaxQty()) // retrieve "max_qty" from db
                ->setIsLeaseMachine($option->getIsLeaseMachine()) // retrieve "is_lease_machine" from db
                ->setProductLinks($productLinks);
            $optionList[] = $optionDataObject;
        }
        return $optionList;
    }
}
```

5) To create columns named "min_qty, max_qty, is_machine_lease" can use `UpgradeSchema` as follows.

```
<?php

namespace ABC\Product\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4', '<')) {
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('catalog_product_bundle_option'),
                'min_qty',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    'length'    => null,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => null,
                    'comment' => 'Minimum Qty'
                ]
            );

            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('catalog_product_bundle_option'),
                'max_qty',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    'length'    => null,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => null,
                    'comment' => 'Maximum Qty'
                ]
            );

            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('catalog_product_bundle_option'),
                'is_lease_machine',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                    'length'    => 1,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => 0,
                    'comment' => 'Is Lease Machine'
                ]
            );
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Output will be shown as follows.
[image]

Comment: For me save in db and display in backend this custom value were not working. 
after lot of research i found that in setup script you have mentioned wrong table instead of this 'catalog_product_bundle_selection' need to use this table 'catalog_product_bundle_option' and all worked fine. Thanks for help.

Comment: @DhavalSolanki: Thank you for pointing this out. Answer updated.